# How can I calculate the total price of all items in shopping cart?

Tags: javascript

I need to count total price of all products, which are added to my shopping cart. Instead it displays total price of all products and the price of one product, which was added, one on another. I can't fix it. I'll add the piece of my code:

JS:

```
//    CART:
let cart = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(".cart")) || []);
const cartDOM = document.querySelector(".cart");
const addToCartButtonsDOM = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="ADD_TO_CART"]');
const deleteNoItemsInTheCart = document.getElementById("delete");
const itemsDOM = document.querySelector(".items");
const prices0Dom = document.querySelector(".pricesDom");
const totalPrice = document.getElementById("total");
const totalPriceDom =  document.querySelector(".total1");

//    add to cart:
addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
    addToCartButtonDOM.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;
        const product = {
            name: productDOM.querySelector("#product__name").innerText,
            price: productDOM.querySelector("#product__price").innerText,
            quantity: 1,
        };
        const isInCart = (cart.filter(cartItem => (cartItem.name === product.name)).length > 0);
        if (!isInCart) {
            insertItemToDOM(product);
            cart.push(product);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
            addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = "In Cart";
            deleteNoItemsInTheCart.remove();
            totalPriceDom1();
        }
    });
});

//    display items, which were added to cart, in a basket message:
function insertItemToDOM(product) {
    cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div class="cartDOM"><br>
    <p>${product.name}<br>${product.price}</p></div>`);
}

//    delete all:
function deleteAllButton() {
    cartDOM.remove();
    itemsDOM.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p class="noItems">No
    items in the cart</p>`);
    totalPriceDom.remove();
    prices0Dom.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p class="prices0Dom">Total price: 0$</p>`);
}

// calculate total price
function calculateTotalPrice() {
  return cart.reduce((acc, cartItem) => {
    const price = parseInt(cartItem.price.slice(0, cartItem.price.length - 1));
    const quantity = cartItem.quantity;
    return acc + price * quantity;
  }, 0);
}

//    display total price in a basket message:
function totalPriceDom1() {
    totalPrice.remove();
    const total = calculateTotalPrice(); // new code
    totalPriceDom.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p class="totalPrice">Total price: ${total}$</p>`);
}
```

https://codepen.io/tatarusetskaya/pen/XWpzNZa

Comment: Note that at the beginning, you get items from the localstorage entry at key `".cart"`, but later, you add items to the localstorage entry at key `"cart"`. I don't know if it's causing your issue, but I generally try to keep a set of strings I use for keys so I don't type things wrong.

Comment: It looks like the problem here is that you're not removing the existing element with `class="totalPrice"` before adding the new one. If you only ever have one element with the total price, you should consider giving it an id and replacing its text, rather than adding HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace 110 line:
`` totalPriceDom.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p class="totalPrice">Total price: ${total}$</p>`); ``
with:
`` totalPriceDom.innerHTML = `<p class="totalPrice">Total price: ${total}$</p>`; ``

If you don't want to use innerHTML, then use

```
while (totalPriceDom.firstChild) {
  totalPriceDom.firstChild.remove();
}

totalPriceDom.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p class="totalPrice">Total price: ${total}$</p>`);
```